# Getting the name of audio I/O devices for WebRTC Apps for Firefox and Safari browsers

Tags: javascript, firefox, audio, webrtc, mediadevices

So for our WebRTC apps we are consuming official [EnumerateDevices](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/enumerateDevices)
API. The output of the API for the Chrome browser consists the name(label) of the audio I/O devices. Thus the name of the devices can be extracted from the API response.

But same API doesn't result in similar response for Firefox. For Firefox the result doesn't consists name(label) of I/O devices connected.

For Safari only info is about only audio input devices.

Is there a workaround or another set of APIs/libraries that can be used to get similar info (Name of audio I/O devices) for Firefox and Safari browsers.

Any leads would be appreciated.

Comment: For FF to get the input devices you need to have user permission to access the devices (through a navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia call). Actually in Chrome too, but unlike FF they do remember your preferences by default, so you did grant this permission before and no notice. However I don't think either FF nor Safari support MediaElement.setSinkId and thus have no use for output devices yet. What are you planning to do with these?

Comment: I have to log the  active audio device name (label) during an ongoing call,both microphone and speaker device name. Like for call 1 , ABC Bluetooth was used as microphone and speaker. For call 2 , DEF Headset was used.

Comment: Well you can't.